# Intellij IDEA - no frameworks detected

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm trying to import a large project like this:

Welcome page -> Import Project -> [choose folder, jars, e.t.c]

After that I'm getting a message 'No frameworks detected' and able to click just 'Finish' button that brings me back to IDEA's Welcome page.

What should I do?

Update: the project is big enough (about 1,4 Gb) and after being brought again to welcome page I can see in task manager that CPU's charge is about 60% (instead of 20-25% as usual).

Comment: One important detail: What did you actually select when prompted?

Comment: I've chosen a package with all my project jars

Comment: A JAR file is simply a component of a framework project.  This is like showing someone a car tire and asking them what vehicle it is attached to.

Comment: Is this project using any build system like maven?

Comment: Firstly I've tried to build model via Gradle STS, but it was impossible due to a huge number of jars that Gradle unable to handle